# Parse XML for attribute using Node JS

Tags: node.js, xml

I'm attempting to scan an XML file for a specific "attribute". This is the file: [The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUZ4y.png)

I'd like to parse it for the "file_url" attribute, but I have no clue to how.

If anyone can help me, It'd be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at https://cheerio.js.org/

Comment: Please add the raw xml not the image link.

Comment: Raw HTML as in HTML code or...?

Comment: Try [fast-xml-parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser) (in node package, or browser) or any xml parser to parse XML into js object. And then access any property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node xml2js module for parsing

Code is as follows:-

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
  // you can access file url as given below
  console.dir(result.file_url);
});
```

Xml is converted into javascript object so you can access each attributes just like object properties of js.